# Merged question shows up when viewing questions that need answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176881/how-do-i-make-jacksons-build-method-pretty-print-its-json-output) question showed up when I was looking for questions with my favourite tags that needs answers.

It's true that that question doesn't have any answers, but the question it was merged with has lots of answers of which one is accepted, and since it's locked because of the merge I can't actually provide any answers to it - and the question it was merged with isn't really in any need of more answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that makes perfect sense. I'm intrigued to find that our "tag engine" has never had the concept  of "locked",  so it isn't a tiny fix, but very worthwhile I suspect. Sadly, I can't just cheat and say "closed is kinda the same  as locked",  as that would mean things disappear from the "votes" and "faq" views (which exclude closed). I'm working on it; hopefully we can get this done quickly.

Update: should be fixed now